# MySql networking issue

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm trying to connect MySql Server from my machine to a server, for development using. In the server, MySql is running normaly, but I'm not able to connect it remotely.

I've already cheked my.cnf removing the line "skip-networking". In server, the bin/mysqladmin variables returns:

```
 bin/mysqladmin version -u root -pPASSWORD
bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.5.27, for linux2.6 on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version          5.5.27-log
Protocol version        10
Connection              Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket             /tmp/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 5 min 55 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 1  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 33  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 26  Queries per second avg: 0.002
```

- Server: SuSe Linux
- Client: Windows 7
- MySql: according to the information above.

What would be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could not connect using the MySQL client, I would suggest that the user you are connecting with is not allowed to connect remotely.  That is a right that must be explicitly granted (though most beginning tutorials I have read show creating users that have access from any machine... which opens the door to security risks).

Example:

If you followed the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-user.html) and did something like this:

> CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost';

The user *jeffrey* would only be allowed to log on from localhost.

However, since you state that you cannot connect using Telnet, I would challenge the statement  *"PS: is not the Firewall."*

Several firewalls can affect the communication path.

- Windows 7: If your current network happens to be defined as a public network, most outbound ports are blocked by default
- Server firewall.  Not sure what you are running on the server itself, if anything, but be sure and check that connection.
- ISP / Data center firewall.  Many servers are behind a firewall at the data center level.  For example, with AWS you would have to allow access via the security policy.  At Rackspace, you would have to open a firewall port using their tools.

Make sure you understand all firewalls that may be involved.

@JvdBerg's suggestion is also a good one, to ensure you are listening to all interfaces

> in my.cnf bind=0.0.0.0 to let mysql bind to all

Comment: I made a mistake: my Telnet is reaching 3306 port, but was just receiving a denial from MySql Server. I've granted privileges to my user and now I'm working fine with it. Your information about the standart disallow was crucial. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There a three things you need to connect to a remote database:

1. port 3306 open on the firewalls. Firewalls in server and client must
   open port 3306!
2. in my.cnf `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` to let mysql bind to all interfaces
3. sufficient privileges in the database to allow remote
   connections

If you can not telnet to the remote machine, forget rule 3.

Comment: JvdBerg, is the parameter `bind=0.0.0.0` or `bind-address=0.0.0.0`?

Comment: I had a look in my.cnf: it is bind-address=0.0.0.0. Sorry for the typo, I adjusted my answer.

Comment: Not sorry, It helped a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't have too much experience with Telnet. However, I have to add that your best bet would be to use ssh as Telnet is horribly insecure. Basically, all your log in information will be sent as clear text, and if a malicious user is sniffing your network...

There are open source programs for ssh on windows such a PuTTY.

In answer to your problem,

port 3306 has to be open on both machines. 
and your database has to configured to accept/allow remote connections.

Comment: SSH will not help at all to diagnose a remote connection to port 3306.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I just had to point out that telnet is not the best option for remote log in.

Comment: [Mlagma], thanks for responding. I'm using PuTTY, but I'm using Telnet just to test the 3306 port, which is not responding. Communications I'm doing throught another ways.