# can't connect to mysql on AWS RDS (error 2003)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm in trouble on setting up a MySQL RDS.

From **my EC2** instance I can connect fine, but from **my laptop** I get error 2003 (timeout).

- My RDS instance is configured to be publicly accessible.
- My security group **has** a rule inbound and outbound to allow all traffic everywhere (0.0.0.0/0).

Should I configure something on my VPC or Internet Gateway?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As your security groups are wide open, my guess is that your LAN is blocking outbound traffic on port 3306. Infact, looking at this support page ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html ) firewall issues are listed as number 2 in common reasons for being unable to connect.

This question may help you out: [MySql networking issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358197/mysql-networking-issue). May be worth taking a look at your local firewall settings. You mention you are on a laptop so my guess is your current network is classed as a public network and your outbound ports are being blocked (as mentioned in the question Ive linked).

If that gets you nowhere, its worth telnetting to your RDS instance on port 3306 and seeing what happens. This may well give you some more debug information which could help with the general Googling around of the issue.

As an aside, personally I wouldn't open up an RDS instance to the Internet directly. Its reasonably straight forward to setup an ssh tunnel to forward traffic to your RDS instance through an SSH server. Something like the stuff shown here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/tips-and-tricks-to-help-you-do-more-with-openssh/

UPDATE:
I've never used RDS with the 'publicly available' option (all our setups used ssh tunnelling to private RDS instances). Googling around, I came across quite a few queries in the AWS forums relating to access issues to public RDS instances. 
For example, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=123483. 
May be worth trying the suggested fix of explicitly creating entries in the route table for the subnets that compose the RDS instance?

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. i'm in trouble with this all day!

Comment: telnet from my laptop shows timeout. telnet from ec2 works fine.

Comment: i'm in my laptop on my home network. no one firewall.

Comment: The only place where I can block this connection is on my RDS Security Group? Because it has all traffic opened (just for testing). I really guess this is some issue with my VPC/subnet.

Comment: May be worth adding entries to the route table for the RDS instance subnet(s)? - see update to answer

Comment: I had this problem recently, and it was down to a misconfigured subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sub net group I had same issue with my RDS instance then I identify that in my sub net group I had 4 sub nets from which 2 are private and RDS when pick private it cause connectivity issue. Then I create one more sub net group with public sub nets and attach to my RDS instance and connect successfully.

Comment: To clarify: ALL the subnets you choose in the RDS subnet group should have routing tables that have the internet gateway specified. My issue was that two of the subnets I chose were my "private" subnets, that had a NAT gateway specified for outbound traffic rather than the internet gateway, and RDS happened to choose a server in one of those subnets. Refer to this article if you're not too familiar with routing: medium.com/@mda590/aws-routing-101-67879d23014d

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted answer doesn't work, ensure your IP address is available as an option in the Route Table of the DB's connected VPC.

This can be accessed:

database > associated subnet > route table