# Cannot connect to AWS MySQL RDS Instance from local machine

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I continue to receive the following error message when attempting to connect to AWS MySQL RDS instance, both with SequelPro and the mysql command line interface:

```
Enter password:^@ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'endpoint_url_or_rds_instance' (60)
```

When connecting I use the following command as defined here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

```
mysql -h db_name.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p
```

I've reset the password, just to confirm it isn't anything authorization related and no luck.

The RDS instance is connected to my own security group. The security group in question has a MySQL/Aurora inbound rule for TCP port 3306 from my IP address. I tried from anywhere too but again the same error results. (I also added an outbound rule with both these connections too.)

Looking up on Stack Overflow appears that since I'm attempting to connect from my laptop a problem could be my own port isn't open: [can't connect to mysql on AWS RDS (error 2003)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705465/cant-connect-to-mysql-on-aws-rds-error-2003). Using Mac's Network Utility Port Scan I find it isn't listed as open when I specify my own IP address and port 3306 but when I telnet to localhost port 3306 I can connect fine. I'm unclear then what else could be causing this issue. Thoughts?

Comment: make sure to select `Yes` at the question _Publicly Accessible_ as shown in the screenshot of the answer I referenced

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHenri I hadn't come across that question I will look into it

Comment: It is RDS in the cloud that needs 3306. For your mac it will not have anything to do with 3306 just an ephemeral port

Comment: Hmmm and the RDS instance is Publicly Accessible still no luck. And connecting as mysql -h db_name.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u mymasteruser -p is still fruitless.

Comment: If it is publicly accessible but you can't connect, then you need to open the port in the Security Group assigned to the RDS instance.

Comment: Correct, an Inbound rule for MYSQL TCP Port 3306 with my IP address has been assigned. Yet it returns the 2003 error. I've confirmed both separately in the VPC's security group the RDS instance is assigned to and on the RDS instance itself when however over the authorization settings.

Comment: step by step ... can you connect from an ec2 instance ?

Comment: For me, checking 'Publicly Accessible' did the trick